# Connecting hdd containing ubuntu to another pc

Tags: hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu on an external hard disk and generally connect it to only one of my PCs.

But if I connect it to any other PC, will the data be lost or will it be intact? Can I continue my work there?

Comment: Yes you can do what you want, I did it for ~3 years without issue but my needs changed and it wasn't needed anymore so I use normal installs (with shared network drive) now.  You didn't provide specifics as to release/desktop/use-case (desktop|server) nor details of hardware variation in your intended circumstance. I built a 'test' machine & fully tested what I wanted to do, tweaked it to work on each machine I expected to need to 'borrow' and when it was good, then installed & setup up my drive correctly. What tweaks you'll need will vary on your OS/release & machines intended to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Such stunts are a bit risky, especially when you update the GRUB boot loader or update the EFI partition on the any of the computers (the old one or the new one), and you don't know what you are doing. This will not result in any data loss. But the drive will not be bootable on the new computer if the EFI entry is not added for this drive. And if the EFI partition for the old computer is present on this drive, then that computer will be unbootable.

However you will be able to access the data from this drive like a normal external hard disk, but natively only from another Linux based OS, but not impossible for Windows.

In the worst situation, this drive will be unbootable, but the data will not be lost unless you format it. There are softwares that will recover data from a formatted disk too.